# How can I hide a control when the user taps outside it

Tags: windows-mobile

In we are using a UserControl as an on screen menu in our windows mobile application.
This is closed by clicking on the same button that is used to open the menu.
As an improvement we would like to close the menu any time the user clicks outside the control.

Currently we have tried by trigging on the "lostFocus" event and using the menu.Focus() every time the menu is shown. The problem is that the lostFocus-event is fired right away when menu.Focus() is called.

Is there any way to hinder the focus to be lost directly?
or
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So when you select a menu, the Focus() call results in lastFocus() being called? A bit weird, no?

Comment: Yes, first the GotFocus event is triggered, the the LostFocus event.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Add 2 `Boolean` values:

```
bool userControlFocused;
bool menuFocused;
```

When your `LostFocus` events fire:

```
private void UserControl1_LoseFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  userControlFocused = UserControl1.Focused;
  if (!userControlFocused && !menuFocused) {
    Close();
  }
}

private void Menu_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  menuFocused = Menu1.Focused;
  if (!userControlFocused && !menuFocused) {
    Close();
  }
}
```

Just throwing around some ideas, here.